# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and working on exercises. One of them is to code a voting system to select the best player between 23 players of the match using lists.

I'm using `Python3`.

My code:

```
players= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
vote = 0
cont = 0

while(vote >= 0 and vote <23):
    vote = input('Enter the name of the player you wish to vote for')
    if (0 < vote <=24):
        players[vote +1] += 1;cont +=1
    else:
        print('Invalid vote, try again')
```

I get

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

But I don't have any strings here, all variables are integers.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Change

```
vote = input('Enter the name of the player you wish to vote for')
```

to

```
vote = int(input('Enter the name of the player you wish to vote for'))
```

You are getting the input from the console as a string, so you must cast that input string to an `int` object in order to do numerical operations.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Python3.x `input` will return a string,so you should use `int` method to convert string to integer.

[Python3 Input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

By the way,it's a good way to use `try` `catch` if you want to convert string to int:

```
try:
  i = int(s)
except ValueError as err:
  pass
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the input function it automatically turns it into a string. You need to go:

```
vote = int(input('Enter the name of the player you wish to vote for'))
```

which turns the input into a int type value

Answer (score 3):

`input()` by default takes the input in form of strings.

```
if (0<= vote <=24):
```

vote takes a string input (suppose `4`,`5`,etc) and becomes uncomparable.

The correct way is: `vote = int(input("Enter your message")`will convert the input to integer (`4` to 4 or `5` to 5 depending on the input)