# '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done": 
      break
    try:
        inp = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid Input") 
        continue
    if largest is None or num > largest:
      largest = inp

    if smallest is None or num < smallest:
      smallest = inp

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Smallest is", smallest)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)

Comment: Post your code here. It's no good to us as an image

Answer (score 0):

when you get back a number from the input method it is type "str"
for example:

```
>>> num = input("enter num:")
enter num:5
>>> type(num)
<class 'str'>
```

you fix that with writing

```
num = int(num)
```

Comment: be ware you turn inp to an integer but still use num with the '>' operator

Comment: there is no problem with inp you just have to use int(num) when comparing