# Error in finding factorial of 1st n numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new with python and am stuck at an error. I am trying to write a code to find factorial of 1st n numbers and the code is like

```
n = input ("Enter a number")
num = 1
while n>=0:
    n = num*n
    n = n-1

  print ("factorial of number is:",n)
```

and the error is

```
<ipython-input-10-2963b5e3e21e> in <module>()
      1 n = input ("Enter a number")
      2 num = 1
----> 3 while n>=0:
      4     n = num*n
      5     n = n-1

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)

Answer (score 2):

The input is read as string, convert it to int

```
n=int(input ("Enter a number"))
```

Changes to be made :

1. Run the loop till 1, not 0
2. Multiply to store into num every time not n
3. Print num as answer

Made the changes:

```
n = int(input ("Enter a number"))
num = 1
while n>0:
    num = num*n
    n = n-1

print ("factorial of number is:",num)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there some problem in the logic because my output of this code is always 0.

Comment: @shivani check it out now

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine you `num` var, not `n`.
Here is a code:

```
n = int(input ('Enter a number\n> '))
num = 1
while n:
    num *= n
    n -= 1

print('factorial of number is:', num)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful