# Flask TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to learn Flash by doing exercise, but I got an error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'".

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/fib/<int:n>/')

def fibo(n):
    n = format(n)
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fibo(n -1) + fibo(n -2)
```

Comment: What do you think that format line does? Why have you used it?

Comment: `format(n)` is basically `str(n)`

Comment: somewhat dupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/ (at the very least, you will find an answer there)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I used it to get the result of the function to the app.route

Comment: Er, what? It has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a mathematical comparison between a string and an integer. You need to convert n to a number before comparing it to see if it is less than 2. This means changing `format(n)` to some other function to convert n to a number.

Please mark as correct if this helps.