# % function returns TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning Python and was writing a small program to determine if someone gives an even or odd number. This should be done by using the % function according to my research.

However when I try the below code it returns a TypeError.

```
numberA = input('Please enter a number ')

mod = numberA % 2

if numberA > 0:
    print('Odd')
else:
    print('Even')
```

I expect the mod line to work, but the program gives a TypeError in the active shell.

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int) - different error, but same problem and same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function returns a String and not an integral value. You need to convert it to such first, using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

```
numberA = int(input('Please enter a number '))

mod = numberA % 2

if numberA > 0:
    print('Odd')
else:
    print('Even')
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it's time to go to bed as this was pretty obvious in hindsight....

Answer (score 0):

The result of `input()` is a string, and when the left hand side of the `%` operation is a string, then the `%` operation is doing [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/).

You should convert your input to a number first to use `%` as a modulo operator:

```
numberA = int(input('Please enter a number '))
mod = numberA % 2
```

Comment: Thank you! So obvious in the end!