# I want to replace numbers in a data frame with string based on conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I want to replace the values in the column `Score` with strings. I want to replace `Score>=4` with "Positive" and `Score<=2` with "Negative".

I tried `loc` but it says type error. The error is:

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
df.loc[df['Score']<=2 ,['Score']]='Positive'
df.loc[df['Score']>=4 ,['Score']]='Negative'
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int. Probably you should make sure `Score` is an int type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
df.loc[df['Score']<=2 ,'Score']='Positive'
df.loc[df['Score']>=4 ,'Score']='Negative'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact that you do the operation in two steps. After the first call

```
df.loc[df['Score']<=2 ,['Score']]='Positive'
```

you have a column with mixed types (the `'Positive'` strings and the original numbers).
Then you search for values `>=4` along the whole column: this includes the `'Positive'` strings you've just replaced, raising the error

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

since you are comparing strings with an integer.

A possible solution is to do the replacing in a single step, for example using `apply` with a custom function.

```
def replacing(x):
    if x <= 2:
        return 'Positive'
    elif x >= 4:
        return 'Negative'
    else:
        return x #needed in case you have a 3

df['Score'] = df['Score'].apply(replacing)
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought `Score` might be `str`of number
so that it cannot compare with `2` which is `int`

you can try convert all `Score` columns into `int` by the following code(RECOMMEND)

```
df['Score']=df['Score'].apply(int)
#or this would be OK too
#df['Score']=df['Score'].astype(int)

df.loc[df['Score']<=2 ,['Score']]='Positive'
df.loc[df['Score']>=4 ,['Score']]='Negative'
```

or you can just compare with string (by ASCII )

```
df.loc[df['Score']<="2" ,['Score']]='Positive'
df.loc[df['Score']>="4" ,['Score']]='Negative'
```