# Label encoder is not converting str to int

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science

```
col = ['date','age','race', 'sex','procedure1', 'procedure2', 'procedure3', 'a_diag', 'p_diag','s_diag1','s_diag2', 's_diag3', 's_diag4', 's_diag5']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in col:
    df[i] = le.fit_transform(df[i].astype('object'))
```

For the above code, I get the following error:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Provide complete error message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. You need to provide a [mre]. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to run:

```
df.dtypes
```

first, to check which columns are already a numeric column, the output should look like this:

```
date object
age int32
```

I would exclude all numeric columns then from your loop. Then change the loop code to:

```
 df[i] = le.fit_transform(df[i].astype('str'))
```

If there is still an error, check this out: [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)