# Take a third input called region_name, which is a string. Append the appropriate string contained in region_list to your print statement

Tags: python, string, int, instance, typeerror

Question is:

The assessRent() function above is very handy. The only limitation is that it produces a generic response. Modify the code to do the following:

1)Take a third input called region_name, which is a string

2)Append the appropriate string contained in region_list to your print statement to give a context relevant response

```
def assessRent(region_list, threshold, region_name):
  i = 0
  while i < len(region_list): 

    if region_list[i] < region_name: 

        if i == 0: # modify the string response below

            print("A Bachelor apartment in this region costs " + int(region_list[i]) + " on average, which is affordable")

        else: # modify the string response below
            print("A " + str(i) + " bedroom apartment in this region costs " + int(region_list[i]) + " on average, which is affordable")

i += 1
```

Error message:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: You need to put a language tag. This is python I suppose. And is this the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int ?

Comment: @renat yes python

Comment: @HardikRaval your question is not clear, but the error is very clear.. Please edit your question again, with what you want to do

Comment: @ggeop  I hope now it will give clear idea