# I am getting this code displaying TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

The following code throws a TypeError

```
string1 = input("STRING 1: ")
string2 = input("STRING 2: ")

string2 = []
string1 = []
print(string1)
print(string2)

which_string = int(input("select which String you want to del a CHARACTER from 1 or 2: "))

which_string = True

while True:   
    if which_string ==1:
        index = input("select index you want to del from: ")
    
        while index >= len(string1):
            index = int(input("Your selection was not in range - TRY AGAIN: "))
            string_list = list(string1)
            string_list.pop(index)
            string1 = "".join(string_list)
            #print(string1)


    elif which_string==2:
        index = input("select index you wan to del from: ")

        while index >= len(string2):
            index = int(input("Your selection was not in range - TRY AGAIN: "))
            string_list = list(string2)
            string_list.pop(index)
            string1 = "".join(string_list)
            break
    else:
        which_string = int(input("select which STRING you want to del a CHARACTER from 1 or 2: "))
print(string1)
print(string2)
```

My aim is to write a program that:

1. Takes in input 2 strings
2. Asks which string user wants to delete a char from - string1 or string2.
3. Then asks which index to delete a char from
4. Then prints out the 2 strings

Comment: I am getting a TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' - any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `len()` returns an int, you take in `index` as a string, then you compare them with `>=`, causing the error. Cast `index` to int to solve the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First input in while-loop needs to be integer.

```
string1 = input("STRING 1: ")
string2 = input("STRING 2: ")

print(string1)
print(string2)

which_string = int(input("select which String you want to del a CHARACTER from 1 or 2: "))
if which_string == 1:
    modified_string = string1
elif which_string == 2:
    modified_string = string2
else:
    print("Index out of range")

end = False
while not end:
    index = int(input("select index you want to del from: "))
    if (index >= len(modified_string)) or (index == ""):
        index = int(input("Out of range, select new: "))
    else:
        modified_string = modified_string[:index] + modified_string[(index+1):]
        modified_string = "".join(modified_string)
        end = int(input("Ready to stop? 0/1"))

print(modified_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't point out where this error is appearing, but it seems like you're trying to do `index >= len(string1) and index >= len(string2)`, even though the index is a string as it comes from input and len() is an int.

You need to note that, for now, index is still a string. You're just transforming it into an int inside the while, but the while can't start because you can't do str >= int.

So you should do: `index = int(input("select index you want to del from: "))`
Instead of: `index = input("select index you want to del from: ")`