# Issue on my higher or lower number guessing game

Tags: python

```
import random
from random import randint
import string

computer = random.randint(0, 50)

player = False

while player == False:
    player = input("Choose number 1-50: ")
    if player == computer:
        print("Well Done!")
    elif player < computer:
        print("Higher")
    else:
        print("Lower")
```

on the '<' part of the code, I get the message " TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' ". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `input` returns a string, so wrap it with `int` -- e.g. `player = int(input(...))`  (eventually, you'll find this causes errors with certain user inputs, but learning how to handle all of that is part of the process)

Comment: Try researching the error you're getting before posting in accordance with [ask]; duplicate questions aren't permitted in the interest of maintaining content quality. This is a duplicate of [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)

Comment: ```player = int(input("Choose number 1-50: "))```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
input("Choose number 1-50: ")
```

With:

```
int(input("Choose number 1-50: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the basic concepts of python. When you take a input in python it is stored as a string and not a number. Even though the user inputs a number it will get converted to string.

For example if the random number is `5` and the user inputs 5 too, it'd be comparing 5 to "5" as they both are different datatypes(str and int).

In order for your program to work, change the line from

```py
player = input("Choose number 1-50: ")
```

To

```py
player = int(input("Choose number 1-50: "))
```

By putting the `input("Choose number 1-50: ")` into `int()` you're converting it to the `int` datatype.

It would work now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in your code.

1. `input` returns a raw string typed by user at the keyboard and variable `player` gets this value .i.e. a str. Thus, TypeError is caused.
2. This is a logical error. Even if you change 
   `player = input("Choose number 1-50: ")`
   with
   `player = int(input("Choose number 1-50: "))` 
   your program will not work as you want it to. After the execution of following line 
   `player = int(input("Choose number 1-50: "))`, 
   `player` will always contain an `integer` value. While Loop can stop early if user types a non-zero number because `non-zero int != False`. You should add 
   `player = (player==computer)` 
   after last else block under while. This line will compare player's int value with computer's guess and overwrite the player var which now will be a boolean. `True` if it matches computer's value and `False` otherwise.

Basically we will be using var `player` for two purposes:

1. To store `integer` value typed by user at the keyboard.
2. As a boolean flag to check if user's value was equal to computer's guess or not.

After these changes, your code should look like this:

```
...
while player == False:
    player = int(input("Choose number 1-50: "))
    ... # if else blocks
    player = (player == computer) # check if player == computer or not
```